# Array of doubles to an Array of CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: arrays, swift, mapkit, cllocationcoordinate2d

I upload the user's longitude and lattiude to firebase under two seperate key value pairs and then on the mapView I take a snapshot and obtain the longitude and the lattiude. I had to store them as strings, but I change them to doubles and store them in a 2D array of doubles. I then need to store it in a CLLocationCoordinate2D array. Then after that I need to plot those on the MapView. I am getting stuck on how to turn them into the CLLocationCoordinate2D array and then ploting those locations so that they all show up on the map.

My 2D array looks like this: `bookLoc[[121.09900,56.5999],[123.94949, 45.0099]] //etc there are more points but I think this gets the point accoss.`

I am not sure how to give CLLocationCoordinate2DMake given multiple coordinates. Thank you

Comment: Why do you have arrays of 2 element arrays in the first place? That's a lot of memory allocation overhead...

Comment: I have to store the Longitude and Latitude Coordinates as two different key value pairs for Firebase so I have to store them in two separate arrays. Then I combine them. If you know a better way then by all means let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
let arr = [[121.09900,56.5999], [123.94949, 45.0099], [...] ]
let coordinates = arr.map { CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0[0], longitude: $0[1]) }
```

Comment: How would I then us MKCoordinateRegion and MKCoordinateRegionMake and  CLLocation2DMake?

Comment: You are not phrasing your question correctly. You have an array of Doubles. Now do you want to make from it?

Comment: I am trying to put annotations on the map using my Coordinates which are contained in an array of doubles. So more or less I want to have an array of annotations so that I can put them on the map.